# Deserialize JSON string to a nested class in C#?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm receiving a JSON string back from an HTTP request that looks like this:

```
[
   {
  "size":590,
  "location":"California",
  "report":{
     "Bob":[
        null,
        "12.0.250.0",
        "20130228"
     ],
     "Mary":[
        null,
        "2013-02-28.01",
        "20130228"
     ],
     "John":[
        null,
        "12.00",
        "59123805"
     ]
  }
},
{
  "size":12348,
  "location":"Florida",
  "report":{
     "Misty":[
        null,
        "65492.592",
        "89216753"
     ],
     "Billy":[
        null,
        "789208.w9",
        "65320880"
     ],
     "John":[
        null,
        "89.8056",
        "75920889"
     ]
   }
 }
]
```

The class that I'm trying to deserialize into is structured like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class DeserializedObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "size")]
    public UInt64 Size { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "report")]
    public Dictionary<string, ReportData> Report { get; set; } 
}

[CollectionDataContract]
public class ReportData : List<object>
{
    public string a
    {
        get { return (string)this[0]; }
        set { this[0] = (string)value; }
    }

    public string b
    {
        get { return (string)this[1]; }
        set { this[1] = (string)value; }
    }

    public string c
    {
        get { return (string)this[2]; }
        set { this[2] = (string)value; }
    }
}
```

When I try to deserialize it though, the Report is always empty.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<DeserializedObject>));
List<DeserializedObject> list = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as List<DeserializedObject>;
```

What is the correct way to deserialize the "report" part of the JSON response?

Comment: Is it empty Dictionary object or plain null?

Comment: It's an empty Dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your report class isn't correctly set up. json.NET is looking the keys a, b, and c. Besides that, the value in the dictionary is a string array, not an object. ReportData an object. That mismatch is what's causing the error.

I think instead report should a dictionary of type `<string, string[]>` and `ReportData` should just be removed from the project. If I were to do this I would use the following class (that DataContract stuff isn't actually necessary);

```
  public class DeserializedObject
  {
      public UInt64 size { get; set; }

       public string location { get; set; }

       public Dictionary<string, string[]> report { get; set; } 
   }
```

Comment: I tried using Dictionary<string, string[]> for the report and it's still returning an empty (non-null) Dictionary object.  I also tried using Dictionary<string, List<string>> and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deserialize the JSON string successfully using Json.NET.  The class I used to deserialize the string looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class DeserializedObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "size")]
    public UInt64 Size { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "report")]
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> Report { get; set; } 
}
```

And the code used to deserialize the object looks like this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
List<DeserializedObject> instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeserializedObject>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```